# How does one show that for $k \in \mathbb{Z_+},3\mid2^{2^k} +5$ and $7\mid2^{2^k} + 3, \forall \space k$ odd.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility

> For $k \in \mathbb{Z_+},3\mid2^{2^k} +5$ and $7\mid2^{2^k} + 3, \forall \space k$ odd.

Firstly,

$k \geq 1$

I can see induction is the best idea:

Show for $k=1$:

$2^{2^1} + 5 = 9 , 2^{2^1} + 3 = 7$

Assume for $k = \mu$

so: $3\mid2^{2^\mu} + 5 , \space 7\mid2^{2^\mu} + 3$

Show for $\mu +2$

Now can anyone give me a hint to go from here? My problem is being able to show that $2^{2^{\mu+2}}$ is divisible by 3, I can't think of how to begin how to show this.

Comment: Show only for $k=\mu+2$ because $k$ should be odd here.

Comment: @Mathi of course! Changed accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already shown that the base cases hold.

Assume $3\mid 2^{2^k}+5$. Then $2^{2^k}\equiv 1$ mod $3$. Hence:
$$2^{2^{k+1}}=2^{2^k*2}=\left(2^{2^k}\right)^2\equiv 1 \text{ mod } 3$$
Hence $3\mid 2^{2^{k+1}}+5$.

In the same way:

Assume $7\mid 2^{2^{k}}+3$. Then $2^{2^{k}}\equiv 4$ mod $7$. Hence:
$$2^{2^{k+2}}=\left(2^{2^k}\right)^4\equiv 4^4 \text{ mod } 7$$
And since $4^4=256=36*7+4$, we see that $256\equiv 4\text{ mod }7$. So $7\mid 2^{2^{k+2}}+3$.

Comment: +1 Probably better than what I suggested (at least for the task at hand) :-)

Comment: Thanks! Just to be clear, it isn't necessary to show for $k+1$, only for $k+2$ for both cases

Comment: It was of my impression that we wanted to prove the first statement for all positive integers. In that case we do need $k\implies k+1$ since otherwise we only prove for odds.

Comment: Ah of course! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What if you tried to prove that:

- $3\mid 2^\ell+5$ whenever $\ell$ is even, and
- $7\mid 2^\ell+3$ whenever $\ell\equiv2\pmod6$ (or whenever $\ell-2$ is divisible by six).

And then prove ...

---

If you follow this path the real question is, of course, how to know what you should try to prove? The answer is to look at the remainders of consequtive powers of $2$. You should see a repeating pattern. Take advantage of that.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Jyrki, this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\,\ $ Apply the following $ $ *fixed point induction* $ $  to $\ f(j)\, =\, 2^{\Large 2^{\Large 2j+1}}$

**Lemma** $\ $ If $\,f(j\!+\!1)\color{#c0f} = f(j)^4\,$ then $\ {\rm mod\ n}\!:\,\ \forall n\ge 1\!:\ f(n)\color{#0a0}\equiv f(1) \Leftarrow\!\Rightarrow f(1)^4\color{#c00}\equiv f(1)\,$

**Proof** $\quad\ (\Rightarrow)\quad f(1)^4\color{#c0f}\equiv f(2)\color{#0a0}\equiv f(1).\quad\ (\Leftarrow)\quad f(n+1) \equiv f(n)^4\overset{induct}\equiv f(1)^4\color{#c00}\equiv f(1)$

**Remark** $\ $ So the gist is: successive iterations stay constant iff the initial point is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

We have $2^2\equiv 1\pmod 3$ now one notes that $$2^{2^k}=(2^2)^{2^{k-1}}\equiv 1\pmod 3$$ so $\forall k$ we have $$2^{2^k}+5\equiv 6\equiv 0\pmod 3$$

We also have $2^{2^2}\equiv 2\pmod 7$ this means $2^{2^k}\equiv 2^{2^{k-2}}\pmod 7$ So when $k$ is odd $2^{2^k}\equiv 2^2\pmod 7$ and therefore $2^{2^k}+3\equiv 0\pmod 7$